# How make ticker text to come in single line instead of goes to the next line

Tags: bxslider

I am using BXslider Jquery in my site for news ticker, this plugin works fine but problem is news goes to the next row and expand the whole header which makes website looks little bit awkward.

How I can achieve news ticker in single line ?

```
    HTML
<ul id="top-ticker">
<li>Test TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</li>
</ul>

Javascript Code
jQuery(function($) {
if( $("#top-ticker").length > 0 ) {
    var topTicker = $('#top-ticker').bxSlider({
        mode: 'vertical',
        pager: false,
        controls: false,
        auto: true,
        speed: 4000,
        onSliderLoad: function() { 
            $('#top-ticker').addClass('ticker-loaded'); 
        }
    });

}
```

});

CSS style

```
/* top ticker */
#top-ticker {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#top-ticker li {
display: block;
padding: 1px 0
}
#top-ticker li + li {
display: none;
}
#top-ticker.ticker-loaded li + li {
    display: block;
}

.fl-page-bar-text .bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
background: none;
border: none;
box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#top-ticker li {
    /* Prevent from going to new line */
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* Prevent the horizontal scroll bar */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```